# Llamado multiple en subscribe (Firebase Offline, angular)

Tags: firebase, ionic, angular

Hago llamado a la funcion funciontmp y me retorna de forma correcta un array con informacion, pero al momento de llamar a la funcion funciontmp2, me retorna  un nuevamente el array de tmp, un array vacio de tmp2 y por ultimo un array con informacion de tmp2. Los dos ultimos array los muestra 20 segundos despues. Es posible que se generen multiples llamados de los objetos.

```
<button type="button" (click)="funciontmp()" ion-button >tmp</button>
<button type="button" (click)="funciontmp2()" ion-button >tmp2</button>

 funciontmp(){

    this.apiCtrl.getObjectByFk('imagen', '-LDnDs0UHIHb0JH7e24T', 'id').subscribe(data_imagen => {
      console.log(data_imagen)
    });
  }

  funciontmp2(){

    this.apiCtrl.getObjectByFk('imagen', '-LF0hQpaxxF9GZZkshhD', 'id').subscribe(data_imagen => {
      console.log(data_imagen)
    });
  }



getObjectByFk(model,id,fk){
    let query ={
      query: {
        orderByChild : fk,
        equalTo      : id
      }
    };
    return this.afDB.list(model+'/',query);
  }
```

[image]
Resultado

Comment: no queda claro cual es el problema.

Comment: cuando hago llamdo de la funcion 2, me da como resultados los 3 ultimos arreglos que muestro en el resultado.